# Cannot pip download Python libraries offline for Linux server from Windows Machine

Tags: python, pip

I am trying to deploy a Flask app to Redhat linux server which is not connected to the internet.

I installed Anaconda for python version 3.7 as it is the version available in my Linux server, then activate a virtual environment.

Then I followed the steps in this question [Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement <package>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32302379/could-not-find-a-version-that-satisfies-the-requirement-package) but a lot of issues happened during the downloading steps as following:

1. extract the required dependencies `pip freeze > requirements.txt`
2. download the extracted dependencies in `requirement.txt` file in my Win10 machine `pip download  --only-binary=:all:  --platform manylinux1_x86_64 --platform linux_x86_64 -r requirements.txt`

It gave:

`ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement dlib==19.7.0 (from versions: none) ERROR: No matching distribution found for dlib==19.7.0`

I deleted `dlib`  from the `requirement.txt` then it showed the same error for `gdown==3.10.0`

from the pattern of errors, I thought the issue is that there is no linux version from pip
in the download files, only `tar.gz`
https://pypi.org/project/gdown/#files
https://pypi.org/project/dlib/19.17.0/#files

Moreover, a lot of issues are displayed each time I deleted a dependency from the `requirements.txt` file

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement gdown>=3.10.1 (from deepface) (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for gdown>=3.10.1
```

My question, what is the best way to download dependencies to an offline server?
and to manage nested dependencies in python?
**NOTE:** here is the requirement.txt file content https://pastebin.com/2T9SLhhC

Comment: For RedHat you would download the RPMs to a local repo and install from there.

Comment: what do you mean with RPMs? @stark

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/34873949/1216776

Comment: Have you tried it without the `--only-binary=:all:` flag?

Comment: @user1511208 I am confused, that command contains the `--only-binary` flag, my question was about omitting it. Does the error change then?

Comment: after omitting `--only-binary` flag, the error is changed 
```ERROR: When restricting platform and interpreter constraints using --python-version, --platform, --abi, or --implementation, either --no-deps must be set, or --only-binary=:all: must be set and --no-binary must not be set (or must be s
et to :none:).``` 
@FlyingTeller

Comment: @stark I already used virtual environment on Redhat and most of the required libraries are third parties which are not available on python system

Answer (score 0):

dlib is not a must requirement for deepface. See its required dependencies [here](https://github.com/serengil/deepface/blob/master/setup.py).